# Como ejecutar un exe desde un web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Tuve que realizar un api para poder conectarme a Adminpaq, en mi local funciona perfecta inserta todo tipo de documentos y se reflejan pero al querer ejecutarlo en IIS este simplemente no ejecuta el .exe, se queda ahi hasta tiempo indefinido

Este es el codigo con el que lo ejecuto

```
 public string[] UltimoRegistro()
        {
            string[] response = new string[] { };
            var list1 = response.ToList();
            var currentDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~");
            currentDirectory = currentDirectory + @"fox\addcontaq.exe";
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(currentDirectory);
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            //var segureString = ConvertSegure("S3guridadsiete");
            //info.Password = segureString;
            //info.UserName = "Admin7";
            //info.FileName = "addcontaq.exe";
            //info.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\sieteadmin\";
            //info.Domain = "TSIETE.LOCAL";
            //info.WorkingDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~");
            try
            {
                var process = Process.Start(info);
                oLog.Add(process.ToString());
                oLog.Add("entro a ejecutar el proceso");

                process.WaitForExit();
                oLog.Add("termino el proceso");
                process.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                oLog.Add(ex.Message);
                list1.Add(ex.Message.ToString() + "process vfp");
                response = list1.ToArray();
                return response;
            }

            string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["siete"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                try
                {
                    conexion.Open();
                    string query = "SELECT * FROM lastrow";
                    try
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                if (rd.Read())
                                {
                                    oLog.Add("ultimo registro " + rd[0] + " ultimo movimiento " + rd[1]);
                                    list1.Add(rd[0].ToString());
                                    list1.Add(rd[1].ToString());
                                    response = list1.ToArray();
                                    //response[0] = rd[0].ToString();
                                    //response[1] = rd[1].ToString();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        oLog.Add(ex.Message);
                        list1.Add(ex.Message.ToString() + "query to last record");
                        response = list1.ToArray();
                        return response;
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    oLog.Add(ex.Message);
                    list1.Add(ex.Message.ToString() + "open connection");
                    response = list1.ToArray();
                    return response;
                }
            }
            oLog.Add("respuesta de la consulta " + response[0] + "respuesta 2 " + response[1]);

            return response;
        }
```

ya instale las dependencias de vfp en el servidor
ya intente instalar la libreria a mano en el servidor

pero el momento de ejecutarlo no hace nada, solo crea en el proceso

> 3/30/2021 12:02:09 PM - System.Diagnostics.Process (addcontaq)
> 3/30/2021 12:02:09 PM - entro a ejecutar el proceso

ese es el log que genero.
alguna ayuda seria buena idea

**Actualizacion**
Agregue los cambios al DefaultPool, al revisar en el administrador de tareas si se esta ejecutando el .exe pero nunca termina, al cancelar el exe este me regresa un 200 (cosa que no debe) pero al entrar al log, me muestra el siguiente error

> The 'VFPOLEDB' provider is not registered on the local machine.

ya he registrado e instalado el Visual Fox Pro, instale las dependencias, e intente instalar la libreria.

Comment: Tu pool de IIS tiene permisos de LocalSystem?

Comment: asi es, tiene permisos pero ahora salio un error mas, al revisar en el administrador de tareas, si se esta ejecutando el exe pero no lo termina, al terminarlo me regresa el 200 (cosa que no debe hacer) pero al revisar el log regresa un error diferente

Answer (score 0):

Ve a opciones avanzadas dentro del pool que ejecuta tu sitio

[image: Ve a opciones avanzadas]

luego busca identidad:

[image: identidad]

y al final cambialo a LocalSystem:

[image: localsystem]

Comment: lo he agregado, pero salio un error que no seria parecido a ello

Comment: puedes compartir el  nuevo error? quizá alguien de la comunidad pueda ayudarte

Comment: ya lo he subido al post, te agradezco mucho tu ayuda!

Comment: Segun veo de acuerdo a tu ultima actualización creo que el LocalSystem no te funciona, ahí mismo hay una opción abajo que dice Cuenta personalizada, ahí escribe el usuario de preferencia que tenga privilegios de administrador y la contraseña, en caso de que no tengas, crea un usuario y password y vemos como funciona.

Comment: Igual como antecedente, es muy difícil lograr que un pool de iis levante un .exe con interfaz gráfica, es un tema más allá de permisos, aún así, espero no sea tu caso. Y si lo es, echale un vistazo a esta liga que te puede ayudar a ver tu problema desde otra perspectiva: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911058/process-start-issue-no-gui-displayed
 saludos!